# Drivers for GA-F2A68HM-H motherboard

Tags: drivers

[This is a picture of Settings > Sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jiowh.png)

My audio isn't working, and I cannot seem to find the drivers online for this motherboard. Can anyone help me out?

The result of lspci is:

```
gregory@greg:~/Desktop$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1425
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380] (rev f1)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lspci`

Comment: Thanks. What do you see in Settings > Sound?

Comment: Also, please run `sudo apt-get upgrade` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and reboot, and see if sound works.

Comment: when I type it in it says command not found

Comment: Which command isn't found?

Comment: settings > sound

Comment: No, I meant open the GUI settings program and go to the sound category.

Comment: I have a added a link of a screenshot of my settings

Comment: The commands that you recommended didn't affect my audio.

Comment: - drivers for the motherboard are not the fix. "01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380]"  means it was detected  - have a look at the command line command `alsamixer` and see if anything is muted  - if not install `pavucontrol` and have a look at the settings there.

Comment: More worrying: there is a bug report on this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1574863 Add yourself to the affected!

Comment: Thank you very much, i used pavucontrol and realized that my headphones weren't selected as the output. My problem is solved